# If Shell Launcher isn't available on Windows 10 Pro, why is there an option to activate it on "Turn Windows Features On or Off"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, kiosk

I'm trying to set up a kiosk with a custom .exe as shell, and I'm aware that Shell Launcher is only available on Win10 Enterprise and Education, but even though I'm using a Pro version, I can still see it and activate it on my "Turn Windows Features On or Off".

So I wanted to see if it worked regardless and tried following the steps for a PowerShell script configuration for the Shell Launcher as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher#configure-a-custom-shell-using-powershell). I activated Shell Launcher on the aforementioned window, and tried to run the script on PowerShell, but I got:

> Shell Launcher license enabled is set to False
> This device doesn't have required license to use Shell Launcher

Which was set to display if Shell Launcher couldn't be enabled.

All I want to know is whether this error was really caused by version incompatibility or by any other setup mistake on the code.

Comment: Have you tried to simply delete the boolean check, and see if the shell laucher will work, the check relies on SLC.dll returning enabled for `EmbeddedFeature-ShellLauncher-Enabled` so it's not a bug in the code.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you. Tried that, the script did run successfully but as I tried to log on to the account I had set to be the kiosk, the explorer shell wasn't replaced. I guess it really is a compatibility issue. Thanks anyway.